# Pull data from database using Eloquent and Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

Ajax noobie question here:

I want to get results from a database using Ajax and display the row based on what the user entered into a table.

And I wish to get some idea on how to do so:

Here's my controller:

```
     public function pricing()
  {
    $q = Input::get('term');
    if($q && $q != ''){
        $searchTerms = explode(' ', $q);
        $query = DB::table('pricing');

        if(!empty($searchTerms)){

            foreach($searchTerms as $term) {
                $query->where('unit', 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
            }
        }

        $results = $query->paginate(5);
        $results->appends(array('term' => Input::get('q')));

        dd($results);


        return View::make('layouts.buyresults', compact('results'));
    }
}
```

My form just as an input field with name of 'term' and a bootstrap class.

Eloquent model

```
  <?php

     class Pricing extends Eloquent {

      protected $table = 'pricing';

     }
```

So based on this how would the route be setup, I currently have:

```
    Route::get('site/where-to-buy', 'HomeController@pricing');
```

Which is the same in my action within my form, so how can I achieve this without leaving the page and not refreshing? So the user enters a number lets say 10, that them matches in the DB and the ajax request then pulls that row and displays within a table.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Your question is considered _too broad_ on StackOverflow.

Comment: Only  dd($results); and tried to pass to a view, I understand it's a broad question but just trying to get some examples based on my code to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a dynamic table you can consider using a plugin like `datatables`. The plugin also provides searching, sorting and filtering options. If using a plugin is not an option you can listen to the `input` related events and send an Ajax request to the server using jQuery utility functions (*datatables also uses jQuery's ajax methods behind the scene*):

```
$('#theInput').on('keyup', function() {
   $.get('url', { term: $.trim(this.value) }, function(data) {
      if (data.count > 0) {
          // appending the rows, `html` overwrites the tbody's existing rows
          $('#theTable tbody').html(data.view); 
      } else {
        // Nothing found, notify the user
      }
   }, 'json');
});
```

This requests expects to get a JSON string that has `view` and `count` in it, `count` should be the number of query results, and `view` is the HTML of the matching rows, now in your controller you can call a view that generates the HTML and check the type of the request:

```
if ( Request::ajax() )
{
   $response = array();
   $response['count'] = $query->count(); 
   $response['rows'] = $query->get(); 
   $response['view'] = View::make('row_generator')
                           ->with('rows', $response['rows'])
                           ->render();
   return Response::json($response); 
}
else 
{ 
  // handle the non-ajax requests
}
```

Of course there are many other ways for retrieving/manipulating data, you can also generate the table rows on the client-side.

Comment: Ok that gives me a better understanding thanks for that really appreciate it.